# Check for alphanumeric word and output the same

Tags: python

Trying to separate the alpha numeric part from the string
Eg: If the input that is passed is

```
    BMW X5
```

The output I will be getting would look like

```
    X5
```

Used inbuilt function .isalnum() to separate the alphanumeric from the other words, but the output still displays wrong.
The

```
    name= 'BMW X5'
    if name.isalnum():
        model = list(filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(), name.strip().split()))
    else:
        model = name
```

Expected output X5, but the output out of this piece of code is 'BMW X5'

Comment: `'BMW X5'.isalnum()` returns false because it contains a character that is not a numerical or alphabetical character, a space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `not str.isalpha`:

```
name= 'BMW X5'
if name.replace(' ', '').isalnum():
    model = ' '.join(i for i in name.split() if i.isalnum() and not i.isalpha())
else:
    model = name
print(model)
```

Output:

```
'X5'
```

Problem is that `str.isalnum` returns `True` if `str` is purely alphabetical:

```
'AAA'.isalnum()
# True
```

Dropping a word that is pure alphabetical (i.e. `str.isalpha == True`) therefore does the trick.

Comment: if the name = 'BMW-X' the  'else'   in my code was supposed to return the name as is. How do I achieve this using If-else

Answer (score 1):

By using **Regex**

```
import re
def extract_alnum(name):
    name = name.split(' ')
    result = list(filter(lambda s: bool(re.search(r'\d', s)), name))
    return result
```

Result:

```
extract_alnum('BMW X5')
['X5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with regex instead - borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567867/regular-expression-alphanumeric-words#22567978) you could use the folowing regex to retrieve alphanumeric words:

```
(?:[0-9][^ ]*[A-Za-z][^ ]*)|(?:[A-Za-z][^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*)
```

You can test and modify the regex online [here](https://regex101.com/r/D1sPE1/2).